# Can I change the on_click events associated with the click of the labels in a plotly plot?

Tags: r, plotly

I am plotting the same entity in two different plots. Each plot is showing different aspects of the same entity: one can be shown as a circle and another one is an FFT of some calculations applied to the circle - as you can see in the figure below.

[plotly_subplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TnHH.png)

As you can see, there are repeated labels - since they are different traces, I assume this is normal. Given this, I'd like to double-click a label (for example, the first "A 2nd full - Cycle 1") and all the others would be disable except the other label with the same name - from now on, I will call this "affect the elements with the same name" effect as the group effect. 
Further, I'd also like the group effect to work with the single click to disable all the labels and traces with the same name.

How can I accomplish this?

I am aware of the [crosstalk](https://github.com/rstudio/crosstalk) package and the `SharedData$new` method, but I can't find a way to structure my data to fit this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure about your data, however you can use `ifelse` within the `plot` function as shown below:

```
x=1:5
plot(x, x, col=ifelse(x==3, "red", "black"),
    pch=ifelse(x==3, 19, 1), cex=ifelse(x==3, 2, 1))
```